# google combo charts with stacked bar and lines

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization

Wondering if someone can help, I am trying to create google charts using stacked bars and two lines.I am able to create with one line, but not sure how I can add another line into same chart. I want to show "Average2" as a line chart.

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador',   'Average1' , 'Average2'],
    ['April',  165,      938, 614.6 , 400],
    ['May',  135,      1120,  682 , 500],
    ['June',  157,      1167,  623, 600],
    ['July',  139,      1110,  609.4, 450],
    ['August',  136,      691,   569.6 , 700]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title : 'Month (Q2-Q1 2015)',
    vAxis: {title: ""},
    hAxis: {title: ""},
      isStacked: true,
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {2: {type: "line"}},
 
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
series: {2: {type: "line"}, 3: {type: "line"}},
```

Answer (score 1):

like Sander said, you need to define the bars as standard to get stacked bars. Data-Row 0 and 1 are bars, 2 and 3 are lines. Example:

```
   var options = {
      title: 'Thats my fancy stacked bars and line chart',
      colors:['#FF0000', '#009900', '#0000FF','#00FFFF'],
      seriesType:'bars',
      isStacked: true,        
      series:{
         2: {type:'line'},
         3: {type:'line'}
      }
   };
```

And voila:
[example chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Wfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default type and override it for specific series

```
seriesType: "line",
series: {
    1: {
       type: "bars"
    }
}
```

Now the first series will have the type `bar` the others will default to `line`.